# Silverlight player fails to play .mov videos

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, video, video-streaming, mov

I have a web application that needs to play videos that are pulled from a url's provided. Some of these videos are in .mov format, while others are in .mp4 format. The .mp4's play just fine, but the .mov's don't play (just a blank screen). I'm using Silverlight playerto play these files.
Is there any way to make Silverlight play .mov files?

Url  format are as below:

http://media.ch9.ms/ch9/255c/0d5f8783-ae35-42c2-a076-6626d8c2255c/iwp55_mid.mp4
http://media.ch9.ms/ch9/fdb6/b7834cec-26c8-4d8f-96e0-20e8aa08fdb6/IWP59_mid.mov

Above links are for demonstration purpose only.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can the machine you're testing it on play the MOV?

Comment: @Alexander -i can directly type the link in browser url and browse the videos directly .Browser prompts "allow quick time player" to stream video.then it starts streaming